# Grid layout with grid-row span in last row

Tags: html, css

I have a grid layout in an existing app:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: 16px;
  padding: 8px 16px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100px;
}
    
.card {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #03a9f4;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This looks and works great on all resolutions:
[image]

[image]

Now I want to make some blocks take 2 rows as height, so I've added:

```
.x2 {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

but this doesn't look good on all resolutions:
[image]

[image]

In the final application, I display items in cards and the idea is to make the card height depend on the number of items inside (to avoid scrollbars).

How do I fix the layout so I can set grid-row span on specific items and the layout will adapt? I'd like to avoid JS solutions if possible.

EDIT: I'm adding codepen with my current code: https://codepen.io/Misiu/pen/bGmqVBG?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, so far as I can tell, seems to be the lack of a specific grid-row size for the auto-generated rows. If you add the following CSS:

```
grid-auto-rows: 150px;
```

to the declaration for the `#wrapper` element, then everything seems to line up (admittedly, I did "magic-number" the row-height, so adjust to your preference).

In the following the JavaScript is used purely to assign the `x2` class-name to a random element to demonstrate the adaptive nature of the CSS:

```js
let blockElements = document.querySelectorAll('.block'),
  getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',
  () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.x2').forEach(
      (el) => el.classList.remove('x2')
    );
    blockElements[getRandom(0, blockElements.length)].classList.add('x2');
  });
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: 16px;
  padding: 8px 16px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.card {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #03a9f4;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.x2 {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.x2 .card {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle at 0 0, #03a9f4, transparent);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Embiggen random element</button>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lbfpomxu/).

References:

- [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows).

Answer (score 2):

The case where you are expecting two rows height that rectangle block is on last row. It is not going through display wrap and so its not taking proper height.

You can set min-height as you did for other rectangles, keep height `min-height: 200px`

Here is the codepen solution link https://codepen.io/abhijeetabnave/pen/ExdWyEQ

Comment: I think you posted wrong codepen link :)

Comment: @Misiu added new link, please accept the answer if it resolved your problem, thanks

Comment: I think it should be 216, because 2*100px + 16px gap. But I like the idea :) and the solution is simple!